# Trying to iterate over a JSON object

Tags: python, json, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a JSON object, using simplejson.

```
def main(arg1):
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + arg1) #+ "&rpp=100&page=15")
    twitsearch = simplejson.load(response)
    twitsearch = twitsearch['results']
    twitsearch = twitsearch['text']
    print twitsearch
```

I am passing a list of values to search for in Twitter, like "I'm", "Think", etc.

The problem is that there are multiple text fields, one each for every Tweet. I want to iterate over the entire JSON object, pulling out the "text" field.

How would I do this? I'm reading the documentation and can't see exactly where it talks about this.

EDIT: It appears to be stored as a list of JSON objects.

Trying to do this:

```
for x in twitsearch:
         x['text']
```

How would I store x['text'] in a list? Append?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

```
twitsearch['results']
```

is a Python list.  You can iterate over that list, storing the `text` component of each of those objects in your *own* list.  A list comprehension would be a good thing to use here.

```
text_list = [x['text'] for x in twitsearch['results']]
```

Comment: @PhilCooper -- +1 for +1 for list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Figured it out.

```
tweets = []

for x in twitsearch:
    tweets.append(x['text'])
```